# PostgreSQL - How can I get new records in a trigger procedure that marked as FOR EACH STATEMENT?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables named `payments` and `receipts`.

```
payments (
  INT amount,
  BIGINT receipt REFERENCE receipts.id
)

receipts (
  BIGINT id,
  DOUBLE total,
  ...
)
```

I want to create a trigger that can compare `receipts.total` and total payments which are the sum of `payments.amount` that reference to the receipt after each insert of `payments` records. In my opinion, the trigger should be marked as `FOR EACH STATEMENT`. The problem is how can I know which `receipt` is about in an `INSERT` statement of `payments`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, that's right. However, it is only for the row-level trigger. I may insert multiple records each time. How can I get all new records in the statement-level trigger? Because I think the row-level trigger may have low efficiency compare to the statement-level trigger if insert multiple records at one time.

Comment: Those are available in the transition table: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-TRANSITION-EXAMPLE